# snakemake --max-jobs-per-second parameter ignored

Tags: hpc, snakemake, sungridengine

I am currently running Snakemake on my department's cluster (SGE). For this I have used a template given by a workshop to run and submit jobs to the scheduler and run my scripts within the different rules. [The template for the profile](https://github.com/sraorao/snakemake_code_clinic_2/tree/main/profile) is taken from [this **snakemake-gridengine** repository](https://github.com/drjbarker/snakemake-gridengine).

However, I am running into an issue where Snakemake is not submitting the max number of jobs it should be able to the cluster at once.

```bash
snakemake --snakefile pop_split_imputation_pipeline.smk \
  -j 1000 --max-status-checks-per-second 0.01 \
  --profile ~/snakemake/profile -f --rerun-incomplete --use-conda
```

For instance, above is an example of a command used to submit a .smk pipeline to be run, which in theory should generate 1000 jobs per rule. However, within my cluster, only 10-50 jobs at any one time are being submitted. Within my `config.yaml` I already have set `max-jobs-per-second: 1000`, so clearly it should be able to submit all these jobs at once yet it doesn't.

**Can anyone point to something to improve the submission speed of these jobs?**

Comment: "*...which in theory should generate 1000 jobs per rule*" - not sure I follow there. Do you actually have 1000 jobs to run? (Maybe shows us the job tabulation table from running with the `-n` flag). Are the jobs you have all independent? - Snakemake doesn't leverage SGE's inter-job dependency controls, but instead will monitor until all input-generating jobs have completed before submitting the subsequent jobs.

Comment: Yes, I have over 1000 jobs to submit as even the very first rule in my pipeline is across over 1000 replicates and will be all independent of each other. But for some reason, it only submits 30-40 at a time at any one time on the cluster. I will create a mock up dummy example with a bash script to include as an example here soon

Comment: could it be a limit on the cluster side? I know some admins who d be really unhappy with the number of jobs.